# How to perform np.append() type operation on tensors in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensor

I want to add a new tensor in an existing tensor as last column. With numpy I can use `np.append()`, but I'm not sure how to do this on tensors in tensorflow. Any suggestion?

```
>> a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
>> b = np.array([[9], [99], [999]])
>> np.append(a, b, axis=1)
array([[  1,   2,   9],
       [  3,   4,  99],
       [  5,   6, 999]])
```

in tensorflow..?

```
>> x = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]], tf.float32)
>> y = tf.constant([[9.0], [99.0], [999.0]], tf.float32)
>> ???
```

Comment: solved: `tf.concat((x, y), axis=-1)`

Comment: there's nothing wrong with answering your own question if you figured it out yourself, it might help the next person stuck on this see your work more easily, its easy to miss a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved: tf.concat((x, y), axis=-1)